# How to code multiple patterns for the same match in java

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I need to extract different types of values present in text like simple values ,exponent values etc. For which I wrote different regular expressions . Just I want to use all these regular expressions as a list to identify different values present in text

```
(-)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?   // simple numbers
[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)? *(-|--|to|(up to)|upto) *-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)? //simple range
(([0-9]+ *0{3},?)|([0-9]+,[0-9]{3})) //thousands
```

How to code it in java for identifying multiple patterns in java. I am using java regex matcher
I strucked here.

```
private Pattern Value = Pattern.compile("");
Matcher matcher = Value.matcher(docText);
```

Comment: You have regex patterns A, B, C. You want to do from them single pattern D, right?

Comment: Yes. I want to use D as a singe pattern which should have A,B,C patterns as a list . So That I can extract all types of values ( simple values ,exponent values,long range values etc)present in text

Comment: You should try to make it clear in question, I think you've got downvote because for someone it was not clear enough what you exactly want.

Comment: I thought I did. Next I will ensure it. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could concatenate Patterns with an OR condition ("|") character and round brackets (parenthesis), then define relevant groups depending on the brackets.

Your Pattern might become very hard to read though.

**Edit (2)**

Find below a different approach, mixing Pattern concatenation and group references (no back-references in Patterns to avoid complications).

```
package test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    /* 
     * Pattern for a single numerical, starting with optional -/+ sign, 
     * followed by an unidentified length integer,
     * followed by optional "," separator and unidentified length integer, 
     * followed by optional "." separator and unidentified length integer decimals
     */
    private static final String SINGLE_NUMBER_PATTERN = "([\\+-]?\\d+(,\\d+)?(\\.\\d+)?)";
    /*
     * Pattern for range indicator. Note that "up to" is not intended here as a prefix.   
     */
    private static final String RANGE_INDICATOR_PATTERN = "(\\s?(-\\s|--|to|(up\\s?to))\\s?)";
    /*
     * Pattern combining one numerical, a range indicator, and another numerical. 
     * It starts with a negative look-behind reference to avoid starting the match if 
     * with preceded by a range indicator, and avoids ending the match if followed by a 
     * range indicator as well.  
     */
    private static final String RANGE_PATTERN = "(?<!"
            + RANGE_INDICATOR_PATTERN + ")" + SINGLE_NUMBER_PATTERN
            + RANGE_INDICATOR_PATTERN + SINGLE_NUMBER_PATTERN + "(?!"
            + RANGE_INDICATOR_PATTERN + ")";
    /*
     * Pattern defining a single number neither preceded nor followed by a range indicator.
     */
    private static final String ISOLATED_NUMBER_PATTERN = "(?<!"
            + RANGE_INDICATOR_PATTERN + ")" + SINGLE_NUMBER_PATTERN
            + "(?!" + RANGE_INDICATOR_PATTERN + ")";
    /*
     * Ultimate pattern combining single, isolated numbers and ranges. 
     */
    private static final String WHOLE_PATTERN = 
            "(" + ISOLATED_NUMBER_PATTERN + ")|(" + RANGE_PATTERN + ")";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // single numbers in various formats
        String singleNumbers = "0 -1000 30,000 3,000.00";
        // various ranges with various numerical formats
        String ranges = "0 to 1 1000- 2,000 30,000--40,000.00 4.00 up to 5 10,000 to -5";
        // mixed
        String mixed = "0 0 to 1 -1000 1000- 2,000 30,000 30,000--40,000.00 3,000.00 4.00 up to 5 10,000 to -5";
        // testing single numbers
        Pattern singleNumber = Pattern.compile(SINGLE_NUMBER_PATTERN);
        Matcher singleNumberMatcher = singleNumber.matcher(singleNumbers);
        while (singleNumberMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("SINGLE NUMBER: " + singleNumberMatcher.group());
        }
        // testing ranges
        Pattern rangesPattern = Pattern.compile(RANGE_PATTERN);
        Matcher rangesMatcher = rangesPattern.matcher(ranges);
        while (rangesMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("WHOLE RANGE: " + rangesMatcher.group());
            // note how tough it is to correctly guess group numbers
            // if you use Java 7 you can actually name your groups
            System.out.println("\tfirst number in range: "
                    + rangesMatcher.group(4));
            System.out.println("\tsecond number in range: "
                    + rangesMatcher.group(10));
        }
        // testing mixed examples
        Pattern mixedPattern = Pattern.compile(WHOLE_PATTERN);
        Matcher mixedMatcher = mixedPattern.matcher(mixed);
        while (mixedMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("WHOLE MATCH: " + mixedMatcher.group());
            if (mixedMatcher.group(1) != null) {
                System.out.println("\tsingle number: " + mixedMatcher.group(1));
            }
            else if (mixedMatcher.group(11) != null) {
                System.out.println("\trange: " + mixedMatcher.group(11));
                // note how CRAZY it is to correctly guess group numbers now!
                // if you use Java 7 you can actually name your groups
                System.out.println("\t\tfirst number in range: "
                        + mixedMatcher.group(15));
                System.out.println("\t\tsecond number in range: "
                        + mixedMatcher.group(21));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
SINGLE NUMBER: 0
SINGLE NUMBER: -1000
SINGLE NUMBER: 30,000
SINGLE NUMBER: 3,000.00
WHOLE RANGE: 0 to 1
    first number in range: 0
    second number in range: 1
WHOLE RANGE: 1000- 2,000
    first number in range: 1000
    second number in range: 2,000
WHOLE RANGE: 30,000--40,000.00
    first number in range: 30,000
    second number in range: 40,000.00
WHOLE RANGE: 4.00 up to 5
    first number in range: 4.00
    second number in range: 5
WHOLE RANGE: 10,000 to -5
    first number in range: 10,000
    second number in range: -5
WHOLE MATCH: 0
    single number: 0
WHOLE MATCH: 0 to 1
    range: 0 to 1
        first number in range: 0
        second number in range: 1
WHOLE MATCH: -1000
    single number: -1000
WHOLE MATCH: 100
    single number: 100
WHOLE MATCH: 0- 2,000
    range: 0- 2,000
        first number in range: 0
        second number in range: 2,000
WHOLE MATCH: 30,000
    single number: 30,000
WHOLE MATCH: 30,00
    single number: 30,00
WHOLE MATCH: 0--40,000.00
    range: 0--40,000.00
        first number in range: 0
        second number in range: 40,000.00
WHOLE MATCH: 3,000.00
    single number: 3,000.00
WHOLE MATCH: 4.0
    single number: 4.0
WHOLE MATCH: 0 up to 5
    range: 0 up to 5
        first number in range: 0
        second number in range: 5
WHOLE MATCH: 10,00
    single number: 10,00
WHOLE MATCH: 0 to -5
    range: 0 to -5
        first number in range: 0
        second number in range: -5
```

**Note**

This solution is **not** the Holy Grail. Use with caution and beware, this can become quite bloated an unreadable in the long run!

Comment: The order is important, though OP's pattern is a bit weird that I don't know whether he will get the expected result when combining the regex together.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks, you are right - it wasn't clear to me that order was important when I posted this answer.

Comment: you mean something like this. Am I right for first two? private Pattern Value = Pattern.compile("((-)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)|([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)? *(-|--|to|(up to)|upto) *-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)");

Comment: @Hari yes, that's what I meant for the Pattern syntax. Then you would need to get the right groups out of the big Pattern. However, if the order is important or you are requiring XOR logic, this might probably not be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks!!Order is not important for me. Just I should be able to identify different values  present in text. I had around 10  different regular expressions for simple values,exponent values,long range etc. As per you final statement will be too complex. Is is possible Can I give these regular expressions as a list.

Comment: @Hari I see. Then, assuming your Patterns do **not** include each other (that's important), and that your parenthesis are set correctly, you should be able to mine all the matches of your text by using a while loop with the matcher.find() method, and gathering the matches from matcher.group(1) to 3

Comment: @Mena Okay I will try it. I am new to programming.If it is fine for you can please code it for me

Comment: @Mena Thanks a lot for such big effort.

Answer (score 0):

You could have all your patterns in a `ArrayList<Pattern>`, read each line, and verify it agains your pattern array. Something like

```
patternList.add(Pattern.compile("\\w+"));
...
int countPatternMatches(String newLine, List<Pattern> patternList){
 int amt = 0;
 for(Pattern pattern : patternList) {
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(newLine);
   if (matcher.find()) {
     amt++;
   }
 }
 return amt;
}
```

then if the amount of matches if equal to the list size you matched all patterns

Comment: Or there's also the `Predicate` approach.

Comment: @vikingsteve: What is this `Predicate` you are referring to? If it is from Java API, then it is only available from 1.8

Comment: @nhahtdh I was thinking of this one: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html

Comment: @vikingsteve: I don't know whether it works for extracting data from the input string. It doesn't seem to me the `Predicate` interface would be useful for such use case.

Comment: `Predicate` seems to be used like this `Predicate<String> nonEmptyStringPredicate = new Predicate<String>() { public boolean apply(String s) { return s!=null && s.trim().length()>0; } };` however at the inside you still have to match your `string` with the _regex_

Comment: Is the question about counting the number of patterns that matches the regex?

Comment: he could "identifying multiple patterns in java" by knowing the amount of patterns that matched. Without a more detailed question this as much as i can do to help him

Comment: I need to extract different types of values present in text like simple values ,exponent values etc. For which I wrote different regular expressions . Just I want to use all these regular expressions as a list to identify different values present in text

Comment: @Hari So, do you want to know exactly which expresions match wich each line?

Comment: @fGo no need. At last all values present in text should be extracted or identified thats it.

Comment: then is some sort of compiler